# CentOS Запуск .js файлов в фоновом режиме

Tags: javascript

Есть js файл и php файл. PHP файл лежит на сервере и будет принимать данные post от js, который нужно чтобы работал в фоновом режиме целыми днями. Как можно запустить js файл в фоновом режиме на сервере CentOS? JS будет обрабатывать код и отправлять методом POST используя AJAX в PHP файл на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно JS работает на браузере, а запросы можно отправлять используя CURL.

Если это какой нибудь серверный JS(Node.js), и задача в том чтобы он работал в фоновом режиме то можно использовать pm2.

Comment: Мне нужно выполнение JS в по крону в фоновом режиме, node.js не использую.

Comment: JS на сервере можно исполнять только с node.js и то если там не используется объект window

Comment: node.js будет мешать работе моего веб-сервера? Или он просто будет установлен, и просто через него будет запускаться скрипт?

Comment: нет он может работать на любом порте который вы зададитею

Comment: А зачем мне задавать ему порт? Мне нужно просто, чтобы js запускал и выполнял свои функции, доступ извне мне не нужен к node.js

Comment: Мне просто нужно запустить js файл по крону в нужное время, чтобы он работал весь день, и так каждый день.

Comment: Извините за вопрос, но можете задачу более подробно описать что может я смогу вам помочь

Comment: В общем задача такая, есть сайт на веб-сервере. Мне нужен скрипт с поддержкой таймера. Скрипт нужен на php или JS. Ну на php такой возможности нет, а на js есть. Нужно в определённое время на самом сервере запускать js файл, который будет работать целый день до вечера и отправлять/получать данные от php файла.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usleep.php вам надо прочитать это

Comment: Нет, это мне не подойдёт. Мне нужен именно функционал, как таймер в JS. И PHP забьет сервер, если будет висеть целый день. Скрипт будет работать без остановок.